# Windows Batch script to get substring of filenames in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I would like to loop through a folder and obtain only the last 13 characters of the file names. Part of what I did is as follows:

```
for /r . %%g in (*.pdf) do (
    set var=%%~g
    echo %var:~-13%
)
```

The problem I have is that it is only printing one file name for all the files in the folder. E.g I have the following file names as input :

```
ARC_1384343086954570285.pdf, 
ARC_1384343288950263728.pdf, 
ARC_1384343297950370887.pdf.
```

The output comes out as :

```
950370887.pdf
950370887.pdf
950370887.pdf
```

Answer (score 4):

Any time you set a variable inside of a for loop, you have to use delayedexpansion to access it.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r . %%g in (*.pdf) do (
    set var=%%~g
    echo !var:~-13!
)
```